# Running custom pom.xml in child module of Maven Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a java maven project which has 1 parent pom and 3 child modules associated with it. One of the child module has a custom pom.xml alongwith the default pom.xml. 
If I run mvn clean install on Parent pom, all the 3 child modules (with default pom.xml) gets executed.
I wanted to run custom pom.xml instead of default pom.xml for one of the child module.
I tried below:

```
mvn -pl module1,module2/custom.xml,module3 clean install
```

But it didn't work and I got below error:
[ERROR] [ERROR] Could not find the selected project in the reactor:module2/custom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having custom pom for one module, you can use maven profile to achieve custom behavior in some build.

You can run maven build with:

```
mvn -P profile_name clean install
```